# SQL EMP & DEPT - annual salary, commision

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

List name, annual salary and commision of all Sales whose monthly salary is greater than their commision. the output should be ordered by salary, highest first, if two or more employees have the same salary sort by employee name, within the Lowest salary order.

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Welcome to SO. I recommend reading [ask] and [mcve], and taking the [tour] if you haven't already. SO isn't a code-writing service, you need to clearly state your question and show what you have done so far to try and solve it, what code you have written, and what you are having a problem with in order for people to effectively help you.

Comment: 'Select ename, sal*12 as annualsal, com
From EMP_TABLE
where job = 'sales'
and SAL < COM
order by sal'

I am basically not able to understand ** if two or more employees have the same salary sort by employee name, within the highest salary order**

Comment: You can [edit] your question (either use that link or the one on the left underneath the question) to add the relevant details, rather than posting them as comments

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please take a minute to take the [tour], especially [ask]. Sample data is best served as [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) + [DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language). Please [edit] your question to include it, your current attempt and your desired results. For more details, [read this.](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)

Comment: Seems a homework to me ? isn't it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the query mentioned in the comments i think you need ROW NUMBER OVER PARTITION. An example would be along the lines

```
  Select ename, sal*12 as annualsal, com
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY sal ORDER BY ename) as RowOrder FROM EMP_TABLE
  WHERE sal < COM
  Order by sal Desc
```

Comment: The question says, "salary is greater than their commision", so in the where clause: sal<COM is wrong.

Comment: @MEdwin the query was copied from the OP comments just to serve as an example